# Как вывести UML диаграммы классов?

Tags: eclipse, java

Eclipse SDK 3.7: как вывести UML диаграммы классов программы, написанной на Java и возможно ли это?

Answer (score 1):

умеет рисовать по коду и генерировать код по диаграмме - [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Если завтра, как обещали, не выпустят AgileJ с исправленной ошибкой использую программу которую вы посоветовали.

Comment: может понадобится:   
для рисования sequence диаграм пользовался вот таким сайтом - [websequencediagrams][1] очень забавная, простая и удобная вещь (покликайте по картинкам)


  [1]: http://www.websequencediagrams.com/

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте http://www.agilej.com/

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Единственное жаль что в  эклипсе 3.7 возникает ошибка, но в контактах сказали что ее исправляют.

Answer (score 0):

Простая и бесплатная программа которая построит UML диаграммы классов из java проекта. Пока доступна Desktop версия, но скоро появятся плагины для IDEA и Eclipse. http://www.java2uml.ru/index.html